# Sendcloud return label

Tags: javascript, http, google-sheets, post

I am trying to set up automatic generation of Sendcloud return label by clicking a button on a google sheet. I have made a script for it, but I keep having new problems to generate the return label.

I have looked into the sendcloud API documentation a lot, but still, the issue remains.

I am using this code :

```
`function createReturnLabel() {
  // Set up API credentials
  var apiKey = 'my API';
  var apiSecret = 'my API';
  var auth = Utilities.base64Encode(apiKey + ":" + apiSecret);

  // Set up parcel details
  var parcel = {
    "parcel": {
      "is_return": true,
      "from_name": "John Doe",
      "from_company_name": "FlowerShop",
      "from_email": "Johndoe@hotmail.com",
      "from_telephone": "+31611423344",
      "from_street_name": "Fürstenrieder Str.",
      "from_house_number": "70",
      "from_address_2": "",
      "from_city": "Munich",
      "from_country": "DE",
      "from_postal_code": "80686",
      "weight": "3.49",
      "postal_code": "5722",
      "length": "31.5",
      "width": "27.2",
      "height": "12.7",
      "shipment": {
        "id": 1, // Example return method
        "name": "DPD AT Return 0-20kg"
      },
      "request_label": true
    }
  };

  // Log the payload
  Logger.log("Payload: " + JSON.stringify(parcel));

  // Send API request to create return label
  var options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'headers': {
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + auth,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    'payload': JSON.stringify(parcel)
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://panel.sendcloud.sc/api/v2/parcels', options);

  // Log the response
  Logger.log("Response: " + response.getContentText());

  // Parse response
  var json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  var labelUrl = json.parcel.label.normal_printer[0];

  // Download label
  var labelBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(labelUrl).getBlob();`
```

I keep getting this error :
"Exception: Request failed for https://panel.sendcloud.sc returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"error":{"code":400,"request":"api/v2/parcels","message":"address: "This field is required.", city: "This field is required.", country: "This... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)"

Although I have already filled those field in a form_* format, as explained on the documentation.

Would you guys have any idea about it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I work at Sendcloud in Customer Support so I can 100% help you out here. The issue is, if you still have it, that you are not setting the destination address. While you have set the from address, it is mandatory to tell where the parcel is also being returned to. So you need to add the following fields:

`name`

`address`

`city`

`postal_code`

`country`

`email_address`